# Convert string to array with keys

Tags: php

Wi,
I have string:

`sortAfter=1&searchString=vsfweew`

How can I convert it to array:

```
Array
(
    [sortAfter] => 1
    [searchString] => vsfweew
)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'sortAfter=1&searchString=vsfweew';
parse_str($str, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: You posted answer after 10 min that is exact duplicate of @12emam answer.

Comment: @Mohammad answer of *12emam* is just plagiarized example from PHP docs. Specifically Example #1 from the PHP docs: php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'sortAfter=1&searchString=vsfweew';

parse_str($str, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

While parse_str() is certainly convenient, there is another option using preg_split() as follows:

```
<?php

$str = "sortAfter=1&searchString=vsfweew";

list($e1,$sortAfter,$e2,$searchString) = preg_split("/=|&/",$str);
$arr[$e1] = $sortAfter;
$arr[$e2] = $searchString;
print_r($arr);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/McA9l#output)

Preg_split() splits a string into an array whose values can then be assigned to a list of variables which include in this case variables that correspond to element names while others refer to element values.  The list variables are then used to build a new array $arr.